# jQuery posting to an external php file not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am not sure why but the post to my external PHP file is not working. The post request is not being received by the PHP file as nothing is being outputted.

Here's my jQUery;

```
 $.post("AJAX/get_track_info.php", { url: "uploads/19c9aa51c821952c81be46ca9b2e9056.mp3"}, function(info){
 $('#loadInfo').html(info);
 });
```

And in the PHP file is just a

```
$trackurl = $_POST['url'];
```

Comment: yes its a url for an mp3 file

Comment: jQuery part looks fine, you should check your php script and the server settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'AJAX/get_track_info.php',
            data: { url: "uploads/19c9aa51c821952c81be46ca9b2e9056.mp3" },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  },
            error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

Comment: You're pimping your own answer with a comment?

Comment: I was just typing the same thing! :)